# How to use RSpec's an_instance_of matcher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

It's unclear why the following spec is failing.  If I change the an_instance_of to the anything() matcher the spec passes.  Am I not using it correctly?

```
controller.should_receive(:authorize!).with(:show, an_instance_of(Network))
get :new


Failure/Error: get :new
       #<AffiliationsController:0x007ff5c607f238> received :authorize! with unexpected arguments
         expected: (:show, #<RSpec::Mocks::ArgumentMatchers::InstanceOf:0x007ff5c6081600 @klass=Network(id: integer, creator_id: integer, name: string, zipcode: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, allows_invitations: boolean, network_type_id: integer, active: boolean, fee: decimal, invitation_standard_text: text, description: text)>)
              got: (:show, Network(id: integer, creator_id: integer, name: string, zipcode: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, allows_invitations: boolean, network_type_id: integer, active: boolean, fee: decimal, invitation_standard_text: text, description: text))
```

I am trying to test that a controller is making a call to CanCan's load_and_authorize_resource method.  I would ideally have an expectation on the find but couldn't get it to work.  Something like:

```
network = stub
Network.should_receive(:new).and_return(stub)
controller.should_receive(:authorize!).with(:show, network)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's receiving the message with the actual Network class and not an instance of it.

Comment: Can you detail what change made this test pass?  Running into this myself.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765512/an-instance-of-mailmessage-not-returning-true