# How should I test CanCan's load_and_authorize_resource is being called in my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cancan

I have another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425185/how-to-use-rspecs-an-instance-of-matcher) trying a different approach to testing that the resource is being loaded and authorized in the controller, but it seems like I am borderline testing CanCan itself.  I've looked at the [source code](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb) for CanCan's load_and_authorize_resource method and it just seems to be [adding a before_filter](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb) to the controller.

I've tried the following:

1. Checking for a load_and_authorize_resource before_filter.  I find the filters with the _process_action_callbacks method, but I see no CanCan-related filters.  I'm not sure if this is due to how the before_filters are being added.
2. I tried testing MyController.should_receive(:load_and_authorize_resource).with(:network), to no avail.
3. Any other suggestions?  How would you test this?

Comment: why not just see if a CanCan exception is raised when `authorize!` is called?

Answer (score 1):

I'd mock it out using [mocha](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/) or some other mocking framework, with something like:

```
CanCan.expects(:load_and_authorize_resource).once.returns(true)
```

Comment: Was trying this approach - the call doesn't seem to be made on CanCan, or the controller itself. Not sure where to set the mock expectation - but don't think this answer works (although I am using rspec for mocks, not mocha)